# Accessing parts of a multipart/form-data post request in a Java REST web service

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey

I have a multipart form which is supposed to upload a file as well as some parameters. It looks like this:

```
<form id="upload" action="http://localhost:9998/test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="inputfile" type="file" size="50" accept="application/octet-stream">
    <input name="someparameter" type="text" size="10">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

The web service looks like this:

```
@Path("/test")
public class ServiceInterface {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void execute(@FormParam(value="someparameter") String param) {
        System.out.println(param);
    }
}
```

When submitting the form, the value for "someparameter" is always reported as null although in the form I entered a value.

My questions are:

1. What is wrong with the above code?
2. How would I access the file which is transmitted with the form?

I am using Jersey 1.10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, after googling quite a few hours I found the error in my code.

You have to use the annotation @FormDataParam instead of @FormParam.

The resulting code looks like this:

```
@Path("/test")
public class ServiceInterface {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void execute(
                   @FormDataParam("someparameter") String param
                   @FormDataParam("inputfile") File inputfile
                       )
    {
        System.out.println(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant find formdataparam in jersey 1.17. Any workaround for this?

Comment: According to this link http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/contribs/jersey-multipart/com/sun/jersey/multipart/FormDataParam.html there, this annotation should be included in Jersey 1.17. Did you import com.sun.jersey.multipart?

Comment: @FormDataParam doesnt work for me in IE. It throws 400 bad request. any ideas on how to fix that?